# How add collection into collection form in symfony 3

Tags: symfony, collections, symfony-3.3

I have 3 form types in symfony 3

PanneauType which is the parent of all next collections

```
            ->add('faces', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => FacePanneauType::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ))
```

FaceType

```
->add('agendas', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => AgendaType::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'attr' =>['class'=>'agendas']
            ))
```

AgendaType

```
->add('debut', null, ['attr'=>['class'=>'form-control']])
 ->add('fin', null, ['attr'=>['class'=>'form-control']])
```

How can I generate my form in the twig add and remove the agendaType?

Answer (score 0):

That's what you are looking for:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

You are going to need some Javascript for this :)